# Problems Following Links Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Trying to get my webcrawler to crawl links extracted from a webpage.  I'm using Scrapy.  I can successfully pull data with my crawler, but can't get it to crawl.  I believe the problem is in my rules section.  New to Scrapy.  Thanks for you help in advance.

I'm scraping this website:

```
http://ballotpedia.org/wiki/index.php/Category:2012_challenger
```

The links I'm trying to follow look like this in the source code:

```
/wiki/index.php/A._Ghani
```

or

```
/wiki/index.php/A._Keith_Carreiro
```

Here is the code for my spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule

from ballot1.items import Ballot1Item

class Ballot1Spider(CrawlSpider):
   name = "stewie"
   allowed_domains = ["ballotpedia.org"]
   start_urls = [
       "http://ballotpedia.org/wiki/index.php/Category:2012_challenger"
   ]
   rules =  (
       Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'w+'), follow=True),
       Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'\w{4}/\w+/\w+'), callback='parse')
   )

 def parse(self, response):
   hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
   sites = hxs.select('*')
   items = []
   for site in sites:
       item = Ballot1Item()
       item['candidate'] = site.select('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
       item['position'] = site.select('//table[@class="infobox"]/tr/td/b/text()').extract()
       item['controversies'] = site.select('//h3/span[@id="Controversies"]/text()').extract()
       item['endorsements'] = site.select('//h3/span[@id="Endorsements"]/text()').extract()
       item['currentposition'] = site.select('//table[@class="infobox"]/tr/td[@style="text-align:center; background-color:red;color:white; font-size:100%; font-weight:bold;"]/text()').extract()
       items.append(item)
   return items
```

Answer (score 1):

The links that you're after are only present in this element:

```
<div lang="en" dir="ltr" class="mw-content-ltr">
```

So you have to restrict the XPath to prevent extraneous links:

```
restrict_xpaths='//div[@id="mw-pages"]/div'
```

Finally, you only want to follow links that look like `/wiki/index.php?title=Category:2012_challenger&pagefrom=Alison+McCoy#mw-pages`, so your final rules should look like:

```
rules = (
    Rule(
        SgmlLinkExtractor(
            allow=r'&pagefrom='
        ),
        follow=True
    ),
    Rule(
        SgmlLinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths='//div[@id="mw-pages"]/div',
            callback='parse'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: @YoungGrasshopper: See my edit. The `allow` rule isn't correct.

Comment: Adding this code raised an invalid expression error.  It also says bad character range. Does any of this sound familiar to you @Blender

Comment: your previous edit removed the errors, but it still isn't crawling the links.  Is there something I possibly need to modify outside of my spider file?  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @YoungGrasshopper: Just saw this question. Rename your `parse` method to `parse_item` or something. `parse` is used internally by `CrawlSpider` to crawl over the links.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a CrawlSpider with a callback of `parse`, which the [scrapy documentation expressly warns will prevent crawling](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/0.16/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules).

Rename it to something like `parse_items` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`r'w+'` is wrong (I think you meant `r'\w+'`) and `r'\w{4}/\w+/\w+'` doesn't look right too, as it doesn't match your links (it's missing a leading `/`). Why don't you try just `r'/wiki/index.php/.+'` ?
Don't forget that `\w` doesn't include `.` and other symbols that can be parts of an article name.

Comment: Just made an attempt with the above mentioned changes to the rules.  It still only scrapped my start url.